# Best spot for wp_register_script() and wp_register_style()

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I need to enqueue multiple scripts and styles in my plugin. However, I do not like the idea of calling `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` every time I need to call `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`. I think it is a good idea to register the scripts and styles once, then call them as necessary as needed.

So my question is, what is the best practice to using an action hook to call `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` to enable one-time registration? And which action hook is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts and styles can be registered on the `wp_loaded` hook and then later enqueued using `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Once the scripts and styles have been registered, they can be enqueued later using just the handles that they were originally registered with.

```
// Register scripts/styles. They can be optionally enqueued later on.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_register_scripts' );
function wpse_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'something-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/something.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
    wp_register_script( 'something-else-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/something-else.js', array(), true );
    wp_register_script( 'another-something-else-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/another-something-else.js', array(), true );
}

// Enqueue scripts/styles.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Load everywhere.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'something-js' );

    // Only enqueue scripts/styles on static front page.
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'something-else-js' );
    }

    // Only enqueue scripts/styles when the full-width.php template is used.
    if ( is_page_template( 'full-width.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'another-something-else-js' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I think that he `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` you are referencing are functions, not hooks.

Comment: Thanks. So is `wp_loaded` called only once? The reason for my question is, should I register scripts and styles whenever `wp_loaded` is called? or during plugin registration, using 'register_activation_hook()'?

Comment: My bad! Updated answer. Yes, it's only called once. "This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated." see `wp-settings.php`

Comment: But every time I refresh the page, `wp_loaded` is triggered again, right?

Comment: Yes, of course but it's only fired once per request.

Comment: You got it! `wp_loaded` is definitely the hook you want here.